# Prove the forgetful functor $U: Grp \to Set$ preserves limits

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, forgetful-functors

> Let $F: A \to B$ be a functor. F preserves limits iff any for any diagram $ D: I \to A$ s.t. $\operatorname{lim}_I D $ exists, $\operatorname{lim}_I FD$ exists and $\operatorname{lim}_I FD \cong F( \operatorname{lim}_I D )$.

I'm having difficulty showing that the forgetful functor $U : Grp \to Set$ preserves limits. Using the definition doesn't seem to get me anywhere, as it seems I just don't have enough information about the limit. Am I missing something or is there a better way to go about this directly ( avoiding adjoint functor theorem etc.)?

Comment: Have you tried looking at an explicit description of the inverse limit? In both cases, the limit can be described as a particular subset of a product of the groups/sets $D(i)$, and so we could see the truth of the statement as coming down to the fact that products in Sets and Groups are very similar (in stark contrast to coproducts, where we get disjoint union or free product of groups).

Comment: Do you mean to calculate the limit in set? I'd be interested in seeing how that approach works. Thanks.

Comment: This is the very down-to-earth way that one would construct an inverse limit of sets, groups, rings etc, if one did not want to use overly abstract arguments. For example this is the way that you would construct p-adic integers and formal power series rings from simpler parts. See the [wikipedia article on inverse limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit#Algebraic_objects) for a concrete description.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think that from a pedagogical perspective it's important to see how inverse limits have been used in algebra *before* generalising to limits in arbitrary categories, as it motivates things and gives a nice pool of examples and counterexamples to draw on.

Comment: I'm not too comfortable with inverse limits (  I know the definition but nothing beyond that) so will have to read up on these and see if I can follow your suggested approach. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be shown that limits in general can be constructed from products and equalizers (see Awodey's "Category Theory" 5.21 and 5.22 for example). Using this it suffices to check that the functor preserves products and equalizers, which is clear.

Comment: Great, I see how this approach works, thanks. To be absolutely clear, is it then the case that "preserving limits" is equivalent to " preserving products and equalizers" for all categories? Just wondering, is there a way to go about this directly from the definition? In general is this how one would show that a functor preserves limits?

Comment: No problem! To do everything totally "directly", Joppy's suggestion of looking at the definition of the inverse limit is the way to go here. I mention this approach because in some categories, limits in general might not have a nice description like they do in Set/Grp, but as long as products and equalizers do it could help to check things this way. In general the approach depends on your functor and your categories, for example sometimes you might know that your functor has a left adjoint, and so preserves limits by say 9.14 in Awodey's book. But this is a useful method a lot of the time.

Comment: I've just seen the update to your comment, and preserving limits is equivalent to preserving products and equalizers when the category which is the source of the functor is complete (that is, all limits exist). As an example, in 5.25 in his book, Awodey uses this approach to show that the covariant Hom functor preserves limits

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answers have been very helpful.

Comment: Glad to have helped 

Answer (score 1):

If you’re aware that hom preserves limits in its right argument, then you might like the approach of showing that $$U\ \simeq\ \text{Hom}_{\textbf{Grp}}\left(\mathbb{Z},-\right)$$ and then deducing the result automatically.